# Setting a random value into a url in django template

Tags: python, django

On my page i want to create a button which when clicked will randomly take you to a model being viewed on my site

in my urls.py i have this defined

```
>     path('<int:id>/workout/', views.workout, name='workout')
```

so in the template placing something like

```
<a href="{% url 'workout' 1 %}">Get a random workout</a>
```

works fine, however i want to replace that "1" with a random int

Ive tried playing with different ways to define the variable but have not been successful

I have tried passing an array of id's from the view and using something like

```
{{ pks|random }}
```

but the url method doesnt want to accept this

Comment: can't you just generate the random id in your view function and then pass it to the template that way? (The general Django philosophy is that most logic should be in views, only that relevant to actually displaying data should be in the template.)

Comment: It would be better to have a page redirect, otherwise you expose which random page you are going  to, which is not  as random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Python's **`random`** module to get a random number and pass it as context data to the template

```
#views.py
from random import randint


def test_view(request, slug=None):
    return render(request, 'random.html', {"random_int": randint(1, 99999)})
```

and then, use the **`random_int`** in your template as

```
<a href="{% url 'password_change_done' random_int %}">Get a random workout</a>
```